# Qual a diferença entre dynamic e Object?

Tags: tipagem, flutter, dart, objetos, dynamic

Qual a diferença entre utilizar `dynamic` e `Object` no Dart?

Por exemplo, funções que não sei o tipo de retorno:

```
Future<dynamic> getQuery ou Future<Object> getQuery
```

Para fazer *casting*:

```
final myvar = myReturn as dynamic

final myvar = myReturn as Object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object` é um tipo como outro qualquer que é usado como base para os outros tipos e possuem alguns poucos membros conforme pode ver na [documentação](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-core/Object-class.html). Então ele é usado mais para compor outros tipos ou indicar que você aceita qualquer objeto em determinado local do código (o que está fazendo na pergunta).

Se estiver acessando o objeto por esse tipo só pode ver os membros de `Object` mostrado na documentação. Só poderá acessar outros membros se fizer um *cast* para um subtipo, o que só é possível se o objeto concreto for desse subtipo (se não for a aplicação quebra).

Então ele é uma generalização, uma abstração, mas é um tipo regular muito simples e que não tem utilidade específica.

`dynamic` (notou o minúsculo?) não é um tipo, é uma indicação que o objeto pode ser de um tipo qualquer e qualquer coisa que você tente acessar o compilador deixará sem dar erro (não quer dizer que funcionará, poderá dar erro durante a execução se o objeto concreto não possuir o membro que está acessando). É só uma sintaxe para desligar a verificação de tipos.

Então o objeto que foi declarado que será dinâmico permite trabalhar livremente como acontece em uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica sem impedir a compilação porque está acessando um membro que não existe. Ele deixa a aplicação mais lenta, além de menos robusta.

Eles parecem iguais porque a ideia é poder não definir o tipo exato, mas a forma como lida com isso é bem diferente. O `Object` tem pouca utilidade real, você precisa converter para um subtipo para fazer uso específico de alguma funcionalidade do objeto, enquanto que `dynamic` subverte o sistema de segurança de tipos.

Em todas linguagens que tem esses mecanismos vejo os programadores abusando, em geral eles são menos necessários do que parece quando tem disponível *generics* e outros mecanismos mais seguros e úteis. Em Dart não é diferente, é mais robusto e as vezes mais fácil usar um objeto específico, mesmo que de forma genérica. Raros os casos que precisa aceitar um objeto qualquer ou um objeto que você não sabe sua composição.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/Conceptual.md).